# How to send additional data with angularFileUpload

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I'm using **angularFileUpload** module in my project. It working fine but I want to sending additional data with my file/s but I can't.

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = Upload.upload({
        url: 'api/photos/upload/propertyphoto',
        type:'post',
        data:{name:'my name'},
        headers:{
            csrf_token:CSRF_TOKEN,
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN':X_XSRF_TOKEN
        }
   });
```

Photo uploading working fine. but when I receive the data using `$_POST['name']` thats does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

To send additional data or form data with angularFileUpload, you need to include the **formData** key.

Example:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({ 
    url: 'api/photos/upload/propertyfeaturephoto', 
    type: 'post', 
    formData: [{mydata: 'this is my data'}], 
    headers: { 
        csrf_token: CSRF_TOKEN
    }, 
    success:function(resp) { 
        console.log(resp); 
    } 
});
```

Here formData allows the developer to send additional data or form data to server.

Answer (score 1):

Under what circumstances are you using $_POST['name']?

The only difference I can see with your code and my (working) code is that I don't have a type: 'post', seems to be ok without it.

I have a nodejs backend running Express.  Express passes the data values through to node in a request object and I access it via req.body.name.

Are you sure your url is calling your backend correctly?

Comment: oh, I used PHP for backend. so by using $_POST I just retrieve form data. Thank you for your response. I solve it :)

Comment: Here I just attached *formData* to sending additional data with the request
`var uploader=$scope.uploader=new FileUploader({
        url: 'api/photos/upload/propertyfeaturephoto',
        type:'post',
        formData:[{mydata:'this is my data'}],
        headers:{
            csrf_token:CSRF_TOKEN,
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN':X_XSRF_TOKEN
        },
        
        success:function(resp){
            console.log(resp);
        }
   });`